# Installing SAGA next gen binaries in QGIS on a Mac

Tags: qgis, saga, mac

I am trying to use SAGA NextGen on QGIS and every time I try to run a program it has an error message saying that I need to update my SAGA binaries to 9.1. I am using QGIS 3.23.3 on MacOS. I have also tried using SAGA on QGIS LTR 3.28.11 and also got a message saying SAGA 7.8.2 is not officially supported.

Is this a general issue because I am using a Mac? Is there a workaround for installing updated SAGA binaries for SAGA NextGen?

Answer (score 1):

It's common across all platforms at this point. This Youtube video shows instructions for Windows https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VKdaripCups.

To summarise:

1. Download the relevant SAGA binaries from https://sourceforge.net/projects/saga-gis/files/ (Mac binaries are available now). Save the binaries in a folder you won't delete.
2. Open QGIS and go to Settings > Options > Processing, and under the Providers tab expand the SAGANG tab.
3. You should see an entry for 'SAGA folder'. Double click the empty space; you should see a box with three dots. Click on that and point to the **folder** where you saved the SAGA binaries (in step 1).
4. Optionally, if you see a SAGA entry in the Providers tab, you may wish to disable this (I think via Plugins > SAGA GIS Provider)

[image]

Hopefully this will be an automatic process with future versions.